# Append (x,y) coordinates to variable in Matlab loop for function call

Tags: matlab, loops, append

I have scatter plot of several thousand points, which lie above a lower boundary defined by several line segments. My goal is to find the shortest distance from every point to the lower boundary (which is composed of linear and sloped line segments that connect) above which the pt lies, and sum this distance for all points for later post-processing.

I found a point-to-line function script online (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64396-point-to-line-distance) which I have tested in isolation, and would now like to integrate into my script. The function take an array of points (class double) such as `[0.1,0.7;0,0.5;...]` and also takes two `[x,y]` points which lie on the line to which the shortest distance is to be calculated.

So far I have written a `while` loop which loops through all rows in a dataset already saved to the workspace (with the exception of zeroes which I would like to ignore). I then use a nested `if` loop to check if a given point is in the x range of the given lower boundary segment (I always want to calculate the shortest distance to the lower boundary segment above which a given pt lies), and lastly I try to append the given `(x,y)` coordinate of the point to a variable which will become one of the function inputs. The two points which define the lower boundary line segment are hard coded for each segment and do not change.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
short_deviation = 0;
idx = 1;
while idx <= numel(my_data(:,5)) && not(my_data(idx,5) == 0)
    ...
    if my_data(idx,5) < my_data(2,9) && my_data(idx,5) > my_data(1,9) % check that pt is in x range of lower segment
        pt(:,idx) = my_data(idx,3:4); % CURRENT ERROR - Try to append given pt to list for function input
        v1 = my_data(1,9:10); % two hard coded x,y pts which lie on lower boundary to which I want the distance
        v2 = my_data(2,9:10);
        distance_2D(idx) = point_to_line_dist(pt, v1, v2); % calling function
    end
    ...
    idx = idx + 1;
end
```

When I run the current code I get the following error message:

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 1-by-2.
>
> Error in My_script (line xxx)
> `pt(:,idx) = my_data(idx,3:4);`

Now that I write out this code, I think another potential error is that I call the function `distance_2D` inside the `if` loop - I'm also not sure if the syntax for calling the function is correct (little experience here), but I haven't gotten to this point because of the previous error I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that `pt` is previously of the wrong size. For your code to run, it must have two rows, otherwise the data won't fit. You could use

`pt=zeros(2,numel(my_data(:,5)))`